# jQuery File Upload preview selected files

Tags: jquery, file-upload, symfony

i have a form and i need multiple file upload and i start with basic plugin from jQuery File Upload. However im trying to acomplish the preview thing that demo shows, and i have been reading the docs like https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Template-Engine and folow the code but my preview doesnt work at all and i dont know what am i missing.
My code looks like this:

```
<a href="#" id="upload">upload files</a>
<input style="visibility: hidden;" id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="{{ asset('/bundles/testetestebundleblueimp/js/jQuery-file-upload/server/php/index.php') }}" multiple>
<input type="button" value="upload" id="upload-files"/>

<table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
```

now the script:

```
$('#upload').live('click', function(){
        $('#fileupload').click();
        return false;       
   });

$(function () {   
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload : false,
        uploadTemplateId: null,
        downloadTemplateId: null,
        uploadTemplate: function (o) {
        var rows = $();
        $.each(o.files, function (index, file) {
            var row = $('<tr class="template-upload fade">' +
                '<td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>' +
                '<td class="name"></td>' +
                '<td class="size"></td>' +
                (file.error ? '<td class="error" colspan="2"></td>' :
                        '<td><div class="progress">' +
                            '<div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div></td>' +
                            '<td class="start"><button>Start</button></td>'
                ) + '<td class="cancel"><button>Cancel</button></td></tr>');
            row.find('.name').text(file.name);
            row.find('.size').text(o.formatFileSize(file.size));
            if (file.error) {
                row.find('.error').text(
                    locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error
                );
            }
            rows = rows.add(row);
        });
        return rows;
    },
        done: function (e, data) {
            alert('done');
        },
        add : function(e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    console.log('Added file: ' + file.name);
            });            
            $("#upload-files").on("click", function() {
                   $('#progress .bar').show();                    
                   data.submit();
                   $("#upload-files").off("click");
            });
        }            
    });
});
```

My Goal here is to allow user to select files and preview them in a container. When the user click on "upload-files" i want to send all files that are in the container, just like the demo.

Comment: Have you tried the plugin by itself? Try to replace piece by piece..?

Comment: @EricG yes,i tried with basic setup step by step, but until now i didnt manage to make it work

Comment: But did the original example work for you? Without modifying it to your needs? If you provide a full working example, people might be more eager to test by themselves ;)

Comment: yes the original works just fine, but i started with basic setup and im trying to acomplish my needs. Until now what im missing its the preview that exists on the demo, and i follow the documentation and the demo to make it work, but until now i didnt get why its doesnt.

Comment: well, if i take off my "add" option the preview works as i expected, but i need my add option, because i want to submit all files when a specific button is clicked.

Comment: I understand. Is it a problem to prepare a full jsfiddle or something? Do you expect us to find the problem by reading..?

Comment: @EricG here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2ukJA/6/

Comment: if you look at the console. you already see that it gives errors. The `$` is `undefined`, and therefore `$.blueimp`. So I'd like to compare with the original sample. Any idea how to start a chat about this subject? xD

Comment: Im pretty sure that the order of inserting the scripts cause the error. You should include the widget.js too I believe. & tmpl.min.js And the template.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21385/discussion-between-joao-alves-and-ericg)

Answer (score 1):

You are lacking all kind of data/resources.

Have a look here.

[image: templates]

[image: scripts]

Means you need lot more than the jsfiddle.

Now, because I didn't have the possibility to upload files to a location, I couldn't test further. I received an error using jsfiddle, but I'm sure you may have your own server location to upload to.

**Update**
For some reason, your `data.files[index].thumbnail_url` is not set in your `add` function.
The only way for me to get is abusing the `file.name` property:

```
add : function(e, data) {

    console.dir( arguments );

    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        console.log(file, file.thumbnail_url);
        console.log('Added file: ' + file.name);
        document.body.innerHTML += '<img src="server/php/files/' + file.name + '">';
    });

    $("#upload-files").on("click", function() {
        $('#progress .bar').show();                    
        data.submit();
        $("#upload-files").off("click");
    });
}
```